# If Statement to display Label or Button in aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I am new to aspx so can someone help me with the following small bit of code. I am trying to create an If statment in aspx.net using Vb, but I can't get it to work correctly.

I am trying to ask a questions and the user has to select a yes checkbox or no checkbox and depending on the answer either a label will appear saying "Not permitted"  or a button will appear to link to main form.

I am having problems making either the button or label appear when the user selects choice.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Main_FormBtn.Visible = False
    Refer_Label.Visible = False


    If CheckBoxNo.Checked = True Then

        Refer_Label.Visible = True

    ElseIf CheckBoxYes.Checked = True Then

        Main_FormBtn.Visible = True


    End If


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appricated

thanks

Comment: Are you expecting these labels to show/hide when you check/uncheck checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is `YES OR NO Category Better you use RadioButton` Not Checkbox..

Try like below it will help you...

**YESRadio_CheckedChanged EVENT**

```
Main_FormBtn.Visible = True
Refer_Label.Visible = False
```

**NORadio_CheckedChanged EVENT**

```
Refer_Label.Visible = True
Main_FormBtn.Visible = False
```

**PAGE_LOAD EVENT**

```
Main_FormBtn.Visible = False
Refer_Label.Visible = False
```

Before that Set `AutoPostBack="true"` for RadioButtons

Answer (score 0):

Well as this is on page load, why would you even need this IF statement here? I'm thinking that you actually want this statement within the Click event of the checkbox, not on the page load. This code will only run on the load, not the click.

Double click your ASP button and put this code within the event handler there. Point both of the two checkbox click events to the same method like so;

Page load - You only want to set these to false on the first load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

     Main_FormBtn.Visible = False
     Refer_Label.Visible = False

   End If

End Sub
```

Click event

```
Private Sub Checkbox_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBoxNo.Click, CheckBoxYes.Click

  Main_FormBtn.Visible = False
  Refer_Label.Visible = False


  If CheckBoxNo.Checked = True Then

    Refer_Label.Visible = True

  ElseIf CheckBoxYes.Checked = True Then

    Main_FormBtn.Visible = True

  End If

End Sub
```

For this to work, it will require a postback. Unless you fancy going into Javascript land.

Comment: Sorry I dont think I explained it too well. I dont want the label or button to be displayed when the form loads up at start. I only want them displayed depending on answer. If Yes the button to be displayed and if No the label to be displayed

Comment: Yes I've updated the answer. Your code is currently in load and you want it to be within the click event of the checkbox. If you follow my code it puts both handlers pointing to same event to minimise code. Take the if statement out of the load and paste my as a new method and it should work if postback is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be a form where users go through and answer a number of questions and sub-options appear accordingly there's a number of issues you need to consider. If you want the boxes/labels to show hide when a user clicks something you might need to use javascript/jquery unless you do a postback, in which case you might need to consider that a user might already have selected a number of options/filled out some part of the form.

If you want to share the overall structure of the page it will be easier to give proper advice.